# Schema Extensions GRAPH API Azure - Access denied

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, schema

I am using GRAPH API in AZURE to create a schema extension as I want a custom property so I can query it in my application. I keep on getting access denied 403 error. In the documentation it says we user needs to have Directory.AccessAsUser.All permission permission. this has been added (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-overview). I have tried with the sample (but removed the domain as per documentation)

{
    "id":"graphlearn_courses",
    "description": "Graph Learn training courses extensions",
    "targetTypes": [
        "Group"
    ],
    "properties": [
        {
            "name": "courseId",
            "type": "Integer"
        },
        {
            "name": "courseName",
            "type": "String"
        },
        {
            "name": "courseType",
            "type": "String"
        }
    ]
}

When I run this is get access denied 403 error in GRAPH. and here is my screenshot. and as you can see it asks to check the modified permissions tab and the status for the permission set is consented. HELP !!!

Here is the JWT.IO for the token and it clearly has the permission group :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Click on the "Access token" and copy the access token to https://jwt.io to see if it includes `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` permission. If it does not exist, please try to use another admin account to log into Microsoft Graph explorer to see if it asks you to do admin consent for your tenant.

Comment: Yes it has got that permisison in the JWT.. Any ideas ?

Comment: Also i try a new admin account and initally it didnt have it in the JWT, then i added it and it was showing, but still no joy .. help !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my finding.

When I test `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/schemaExtensions` in Microsoft Graph Explorer, I get the same error as what you have got.

I guess some other permissions may effect the calling of this API endpoint.

I use a new account from a new tenant to log into Microsoft Graph Explorer. And only add this `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` permission. But the issue still exists.

So there is something wrong with calling this API with Microsoft Graph Explorer currently.

Then I register a new Azure AD application, grant only `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` delegated permission. I test it in other rest API tool and it works this time.

So you could choose to try with Postman to create a schema extension currently.

Please refer to [Get access on behalf of a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0) to test it.

Comment: Ah ok ... so you got it working with postman cos you have to create an ad application (assign perms that side) and connect via postman .... got ya !!!